# SQL query to partition rows into groups where lag (difference between rows) is greater than some value

Tags: sql, group-by, lag, partition, trino

Suppose I have a table like

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 10 |
| 12 |
| 19 |

and I'd like to group the ids (in sorted order) into the same group if they differ by 5 or less, and a new group if they differ by 6 or more. So the output would be:

| id | group |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 10 | 2 |
| 12 | 2 |
| 19 | 3 |

Is this possible in SQL? It will be a query in Trino, and I see they have commands like `lag` and `partition`. Has anyone made a query like this that can help out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `cte` with `lead`:

```
with cte(id, l1) as (
   select t.id, abs(coalesce(lead(t.id) over (order by t.id), 0) - t.id) < 6 from tbl t
)
select c.id, (select sum(c1.id < c.id and c1.l1 = 0) from cte c1) + 1 from cte c
```